# How does sqlite3_step() work?

Tags: sqlite

I have a query that I'm running that *executes* in a tenth of a second but it then takes me many seconds to iterate through sqlite3_step(); I'm used to running mysql on a server where the query runs in a specific amount of time and don't understand how sqlite_step() is working. Is the query done over a length of time as I iterate? How does this work with grouping statements? Or is it just returning the rows incrementally from memory/io reasons? Is most of the work done during the initial statement execution or during the iterating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does only the minimum amount of work necessary to return the next row.
There are cases where almost everything is done in the first call to `sqlite3_step()` (for example, when you have a complex query with GROUP BY or ORDER BY), but in the general case, the execution is distributed over all `sqlite3_step()` calls.

In a client/server system, the server must compute as many rows as possible to compensate for the network communication delays, and because parallel operation is possible.
This is not true for an embedded database like SQLite; precomputing output rows and storing them somewhere would just waste memory.